# Weird sorting algorithm

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to print a linked list in order but I need it to be sorted in a weird way and I couldnt find an answer. So I need it to be sorted first by the integer data(obviously bigger comes first), then within that I need it to be sorted by word. So lets say two nodes have the same data integer, then they would be sorted lexicographically by the word.
The linked list is like this

```
struct node {
    int data;
    char word[125];
    struct node* next;
}
```

Any suggestions? It doesn't necessarily have to be sorted, I just have to print them in sorted order

Comment: How many `node`s will you be processing? That is, any time complexity requirements?

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after your struct definition. #thedevilisinthedetail

Comment: @cubrr no time complexity requirements. I'll probably be processing at max 100 nodes, but that will be super rare, so on average around 3-10 nodes.

Comment: @wildplasser lol I didnt copy and paste this code I typed it up quickly haha I love that hashtag

Comment: You could apply basically any sorting algorithm here, but when you compare two `node`s, just perform the word comparison if the two `data` are equal.

Comment: @cubrr Im super new to C and data structures, any suggestion on the sorting algorithm?

Comment: You could try converting the linked list to an array (find the length, create an array of nodes, and go through each element and set it) and then use `qsort` and convert it back.

Comment: The advantage of `qsort()` is that it has the sorting organized; you just have to write a comparison function (also called a comparator).  Your comparator might look like: `int cmp_node(const void *v1, const void *v2) { const struct node *np1 = *(node **)v1; const struct node *np2 = *(node **)v2; if (np1->data < np2->data) return -1; else if (np1->data > np2->data) return +1; else return strcmp(np1->word, np2->word); }`.  I'm assuming you end up with an array of `node` pointers, not an array of `node` structures.  You end up with one less level of indirection if you sort an array of `node`s.

Comment: Sorting a linked list is a bit trickier than sorting an array.  To sort the elements in-place, with O(1) overhead, I'd suggest one of the comparison sorts that involves only exchanging adjacent elements.  The first two that come to mind are [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and good ole` [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: Sorting a linked list is easy: merge sort. Just create a compare function and a generic sort function that takes a function as a second argument, call it and you are done.

Comment: Mergesort For Linked Lists http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only processing so few elements, you could just fit the whole list into an array, then sort it with `qsort`. Here's a quick example. Be careful not to overflow the `nodes` array in `print_sorted` - for such few nodes, you could just go through the linked list once to get the size, then malloc the space you need.

Notice that in the example, `node_compare` works with an array of *pointers* to node. If you want to work directly with an array of nodes, just remove the dereferences at the start of the function and cast them to `const struct node *` instead of `const struct node **`.

```
// for qsort
#include <stdlib.h>
// for strcmp
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    char word[125];
    struct node* next;
};

int node_compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct node *first = *(const struct node **) a;
    const struct node *second = *(const struct node **) b;

    // Order nodes with same data alphabetically
    if (first->data == second->data) {
        return strcmp(first->word, second->word);
    } else {
        return first->data - second->data;
    }
}

void print_sorted(struct node *list) {
    struct node *nodes[512];

    // gather whole list into the array
    struct node *current = list;
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        nodes[arrayIndex++] = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    // sort the array
    qsort(nodes, arrayIndex, sizeof(struct node *), node_compare);

    // print em
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayIndex; i++) {
        printf("data: %d, word: %s\n", nodes[i]->data, nodes[i]->word);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node a = { .data = 3, .word = "ayy", .next = NULL };
    struct node b = { .data = 3, .word = "zzz", .next = &a };
    struct node c = { .data = 3, .word = "ddd", .next = &b };
    struct node d = { .data = 10, .word = "toaster", .next = &c };
    struct node e = { .data = 0, .word = "box", .next = &d };

    print_sorted(&e);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out:

```
data: 0, word: box
data: 3, word: ayy
data: 3, word: ddd
data: 3, word: zzz
data: 10, word: toaster
```

If you want descending order, change the bottom part of `node_compare()` to the following:

```
if (first->data == second->data) {
    return strcmp(second->word, first->word);
} else {
    return second->data - first->data;
}
```